# mysql optimization script file

Tags: mysql, sql, database-optimization

I'm looking at having someone do some optimization on a database.  If I gave them a similar version of the db with different data, could they create a script file to run all the optimizations on my database (ie create indexes, etc) without them ever seeing or touching the actual database?  I'm looking at MySQL but would be open to other db's if necessary.  Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT:

What if it were an identical copy with transformed data?  Along with a couple sample queries that approximated what the db was used for (ie OLAP vs OLTP)?  Would a script be able to contain everything or would they need hands on access to the actual db?

EDIT 2:

Could I create a copy of the db, transform the data to make it unrecognizable, create a backup file of the db, give it to vendor and them give me a script file to run on my db?

Comment: It is possible though on different data optimization steps can behave in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just adding indices, then yes. However, there are a number of things to consider when "optimizing". Which are the slowest queries in your database? How large are certain tables? How can certain things be changed/migrated to make those certain queries run faster? It could be harder to see this with sparse sample data. You might also include a query log so that this person could see how you're using the tables/what you're trying to get out of them, and how long those operations take.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you concerned that they should not access the database? You will get better optimization if they have the actual data as they can consider table sizes, which queries run the slowest, whether to denormalise if necessary, putting small tables completely in memory, ...?

If it is a issue of confidentiality you can always make the data anomous by replacement of names.